# Calling a function using specs2 doesn't call the function

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2

I'm working on getting a test case working with Play 2.1.1 and Specs2 and am running into an interesting problem. I create a FakeRequest to send to a Controller, but the function in the controller never gets called.

Here's the test code (slightly simplified, but with all the moving parts):

```
"controller" should {
"do something" in new WithApplication {
    val controller = new MyController()
    controller.main() { 
        new FakeRequest(
            PUT,
            routes.MyController.main().toString,
            new FakeHeaders(Seq("Content-Type" -> Seq("text/xml"))),
            AnyContentAsXml(<xml>xml</xml>)
        )
    }       
}
```

And here's the main function in the controller (well, at least just the start of it):

```
def main() = Action(BodyParsers.parse.xml) { request =>
    println("main")
}
```

This code never hits main. Strangely enough, though, if I make the FakeHeader with no parameters, and remove AnyContentAsXml, just sending the Xml Element to the controller, then it works:

```
new FakeRequest(
    PUT,
    routes.MyController.main().toString,
    new FakeHeaders,
    <xml>xml</xml>
)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your test little modified showing two ways testing the controller. The reason AnyContentAsXml is not working for you because your testing is mixing two approaches together.

```
"one way" in new WithApplication {
    val action = controllers.Application.main
    val req: FakeRequest[scala.xml.NodeSeq] = new FakeRequest(
            PUT,
            "some url",
            new FakeHeaders(Seq("Content-Type" -> Seq("text/xml"))),
            <xml>xml</xml>
        )
    val x = action(req)
    status(x) should beEqualTo(200)
}

"2nd way" in new WithApplication {
  val Some(result) = route(new FakeRequest("PUT", 
      "/", 
      new FakeHeaders(Seq("Content-Type" -> Seq("text/xml"))),
      AnyContentAsXml(<xml>xml</xml>)))
  status(result) should beEqualTo(200)
}
```

}

In the second approach Play is take care of unpacking the xml for the BodyParser to use. And here is the controller:

```
def main = Action(BodyParsers.parse.xml) { request =>
   println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> main")
  Ok("")
}
```